# How to put spaces between the paragraphs in turtle window and is there a way I can shorten down the code to writing all the text in one line

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.10

```
import time
import turtle
turtle.speed(speed= None)
ElizabethBishop = turtle.Turtle()
ElizabethBishop.shape('turtle')
ElizabethBishop.penup()

def line(words, horiz_pos = -50):
x,y = ElizabethBishop.pos()
ElizabethBishop.goto(max(horiz_pos, -190), y)
ElizabethBishop.write(words)
x,y = ElizabethBishop.pos()
ElizabethBishop.goto(x, y - 25)

def by(author):
x, y = ElizabethBishop.pos()
ElizabethBishop.goto(x + 70, max(-190, y - 30))
ElizabethBishop.write(author)
x, y = ElizabethBishop.pos()
ElizabethBishop.goto(0, y)

ElizabethBishop.goto(-50, 190)
```

I didnt write the text of it here but when I run it it is all squished and text is writen over the other text. So I need help knowing how to add spaces between the lines of text. So it is more clearly seen

Comment: Please fix the indentation of this code. As shown, it will generate an `IndentationError`. And we can't reliably guess which lines you want to be part of each function.

Comment: But when I was writing the question it told me to write the code in that specific place, and I could see all the code fitting into the box below without errors??

Comment: Does it look right to you? If this is your real code, the problem is clear: you have `IndentationError`s. If your real code looks different, you'll have to fix your question. The easiest way to copy code blocks into your question is to paste it, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as a code block.